# Python logging to different destination using a configuration file

Tags: python, logging, config

I want to use a configuration file to create two loggers which will log in two distinct files. My configuration file looks like:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,main,zipper

[handlers]
keys=main,zip

[formatters]
keys=fmt

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=main

[logger_main]
level=DEBUG
handlers=main
qualname=MAIN

[logger_zipper]
level=DEBUG
qualname=UPLOAD
handlers=zip

[handler_zip]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fmt
args=('zipper.log','a+')

[handler_main]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fmt
args=('main.log','a+')

[formatter_fmt]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s
```

I try to use this configuration file like this:

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")

# Logs to the first file
log = logging.getLogger("")
log.debug("unspec - debug")
log.error("unspec - error")

# Logs to the first file
log_r = logging.getLogger("main")
log_r.debug("main - debug")
log_r.error("main - error")

# Also logs to the first file :(
log_z = logging.getLogger("zipper")
log_z.debug("zipper - debug")
log_z.error("zipper - error")
```

For some reason I don't understand, all logging messages go to the first file, when I expect the last two to be written to 'zipper.log'.  What am I missing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the qualified name used in the configuration file:

```
[logger_zipper]
level=DEBUG
qualname=UPLOAD
handlers=zip
```

doesn't match the one used in the code:

```
log_z = logging.getLogger("zipper")
```

Use any of these combinations:

- `qualname=zipper` and `logging.getLogger("zipper")`
- `qualname=UPLOAD` and `logging.getLogger("UPLOAD")`

Comment: You are right.. that's what happens when you do too much copy paste programming; I also had do to propagate=0 in the config file.